# why does a list changed while it's not suppose to?

Tags: python, list

I have some problem in this code.
I have 2 lists, jungle and junglenext. my question is,  why does jungle change as junglenext?

```
from colorama import *

jungle = [['g','f','f'],['f','f','f'],['f','f','f']]

def nextyear():
    global jungle
    junglenext = jungle.copy()
    for row in jungle:
        for character in row:
            if character == 'f':
                junglenext[jungle.index(row)][row.index(character)] = 's'
            if character == 'g':
                if jungle.index(row) == 0:
                    if row.index(character) == 0:
                        if row[row.index(character)+1] == 'f' or jungle[jungle.index(row)+1][row.index(character)] == 'f':
                            junglenext[jungle.index(row)][row.index(character)] = 'f'

def printjungle(jungle):
    for row in jungle:
        for i in row:
            if i == 'f':
                print(Back.RED, 'f', end='')
            if i == 'g':
                print(Back.GREEN, 'g', end='')
            if i == 's':
                print(Back.WHITE, 's', end='')
        print(Style.RESET_ALL)
    print()


printjungle(jungle)

nextyear()

printjungle(jungle)

nextyear()

printjungle(jungle)
```

I expected the jungle doesn't change, but it changes as junglenext.

Comment: (mind, what's the point of creating `nextyear` if you don't `return` or otherwise store it somewhere?)

Comment: Helpful read on [shallow vs deep copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html)

Comment: Not directly related, but there is no requirement for `global jungle`, because the function never reassigns `jungle`.

Comment: what does "jungle doesn't change" mean? Where do you check this?